# how to set system screen resolution on Android hardware?

Tags: android, hardware, screen-resolution, android-hardware

I would like to add to a change in Android source code so Android boots in a resolution of my choice. I do not want to do this on QEMU/AVD, I would like to do this and test it on a real hardware.
Can anybody point me to a place in the Android source code where I can set or hardcode the screen size values?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you just trying to crop the resolution to specific pixels?  Otherwise this would be very driver and hardware dependent I would guess.

Comment: you can do that by tweaking your framebuffer driver. that's hardware dependent, though